# python3 how to create a list that checks empty values and takes the average of the adjacent values to replace the empty value?

Tags: python-3.x, list, filter, missing-data

I want to create a list that gives an output whereby if the original list has an empty value, it takes the sum average of the adjacent values to replace it in its place. Assume missing data is denoted by -99

```
def clean_missing_data():
    
    data_list = []
    
    for number, adjacent in enumerate(a):
        
        if (number != -99):

            data_list.append(number)
            
        else:
            
            adjacent_left = a[number-1]
            adjacent_right = a[number+1]
            fill_in = (adjacent_left + adjacent_right) / 2    
            data_list.append(fill_in)
    
    return data_list

a = [1,2,3,-99,5]

check_data = clean_missing_data()

print('original test case:', a)
print('After clearing, the test case became:', check_data)
```

OUTPUT

```
original test case: [1, 2, 3, -99, 5]
After clearing, the test case became: [0, 1, 2, 3, 4]
```

E.g. For this test case, the missing value is the fourth number of the list (denoted by -99), which means the list takes the sum average of the adjacent data; the values 3 and 5, and replace it back to the list.

In essence, it means: [1,2,3,  (3+5)/2,  5]

Please help!

Comment: You do not attempt to do what you need to do. Whats your problem?

Comment: Hi Patrick! I only did the filter of the list, whereby if the list contains -99, it only returns a new list that excludes the -99 value. What I am unable to do is take the average adjacent values (in this case, the value 3 and 5) and replace it back to the list.

Comment: There are a lot of corner cases to consider. What if your first 2 elements of the list are -99? Or what if you have a string of 3 consecutive -99 values in the middle of the list? etc.

Comment: @DV82XL Hi, we can only replace the missing price with the average value if and only if the adjacent prices are valid data. In the event that we cannot calculate the average price, the missing price is replaced by the adjacent price which has a valid value. So I guess if all 5 values are -99 in a row, then maybe return a simple print indicating unable to compute

Comment: so what if your input list is `[-99, -99, 3, 4, 5]` ? What would your expected output be? What about an input of `[1, -99, -99, -99, 5]` ?

Comment: @DV82XL In such cases that either value of -99 cannot be used to serve as the average for other valid values, then I think I will just have to return a string indicating 'unable to compute'. In the test case of ``` [-99, -99, 3, 4, 5], the function will have to find the next adjacent price to compute the average IF the first adjacent price is also -99. Same goes for ``` [1, -99, -99, -99, 5], if its possible. Apologies, I am not sure how to handle the testing process as I am very new to python! This question here is part of my class exercises!

Comment: If any of the answers below answered your question, please check the green check mark to indicate your question has been answered. Thanks and good luck!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The requirements are a bit unclear, so I'm not 100% sure this does exactly what you want, but this is my best guess for now.

```py
def get_right_number(numbers, i):
""" Recursive function to search for the first valid number to the right """

    if i >= len(numbers) - 1:
        right = -99
    else:
        right = numbers[i + 1]
        if right == -99:
            right = get_right_number(numbers, i+1)
    return right


def clean_missing_data(numbers):
    print(f'Input: {numbers}')

    if all(x == -99 for x in numbers):
        print('All values in list are invalid. Could not compute.')
        return

    clean_numbers = []

    for i in range(len(numbers)):
        if numbers[i] != -99:
            clean_numbers.append(numbers[i])
        else:
            valid_count = 0

            if i == 0:
                left = 0
            else:
                left = clean_numbers[i - 1]
                valid_count += 1

            right = get_right_number(numbers, i)
            if right == -99:
                right = 0
            else:
                valid_count += 1

            average = (left + right) / valid_count
            clean_numbers.append(average)

    print(f'Output: {clean_numbers}\n')
    return clean_numbers
```

Here are my test cases (print is embedded in the clean method above):

```py
clean_missing_data([1, 2, 3, 4, 5])
clean_missing_data([1, 2, 3, -99, 5])
clean_missing_data([-99, 2, 3, 4, 5])
clean_missing_data([-99, -99, 3, 4, 5])
clean_missing_data([1, 2, 3, 4, -99])
clean_missing_data([1, 2, 3, -99, -99])
clean_missing_data([1, -99, -99, -99, 5])
clean_missing_data([-99, -99, -99, -99, -99])
```

Here are the outputs:

```py
Input: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
Output: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]

Input: [1, 2, 3, -99, 5]
Output: [1, 2, 3, 4.0, 5]

Input: [-99, 2, 3, 4, 5]
Output: [2.0, 2, 3, 4, 5]

Input: [-99, -99, 3, 4, 5]
Output: [3.0, 3.0, 3, 4, 5]

Input: [1, 2, 3, 4, -99]
Output: [1, 2, 3, 4, 4.0]

Input: [1, 2, 3, -99, -99]
Output: [1, 2, 3, 3.0, 3.0]

Input: [1, -99, -99, -99, 5]
Output: [1, 3.0, 4.0, 4.5, 5]

Input: [-99, -99, -99, -99, -99]
All values in list are invalid.
```

Note that when you have a string of invalid numbers, we will fetch the right-most valid number and take the average with that. This new average will be considered in the calculation for the next number, etc. This performs a kind of interpolation, but it's not a linear interpolation strictly speaking. Without complete requirements, this will have to do for now (on time and under budget!)

If you need to change the requirements, you can tweak the code above until all the test cases do what you need. I'm also sure there's a cleaner way to do this, but I'll leave that to you to figure out. Good luck!

Answer (score 2):

You confounded the variables `number` and `adjacent`. The convention is to talk about `enumerate(a)` returning an `index` as the location in the array and an `element` as the element itself. In that case your code becomes

```py
def clean_missing_data():
    
    data_list = []
    
    for index, element in enumerate(a):
        
        if (element != -99):

            data_list.append(element)
            
        else:
            
            adjacent_left = a[index - 1]
            adjacent_right = a[index + 1]
            fill_in = (adjacent_left + adjacent_right) / 2    
            data_list.append(fill_in)
    
    return data_list

a = [1,2,3,-99,5]

check_data = clean_missing_data()

print('original test case:', a)
print('After clearing, the test case became:', check_data)
```

which gives `[1, 2, 3, 4.0, 5]`, where 4.0 is of course equivalent to 4

You do need to understand that there are still some problems with the code. What if the first or last number is -99? What if two adjacent numbers are -99? But this should at least work for the example you gave!